Disable Ubuntu Tiling Assistant Resize on Single Click Bar
There seems to be an annoying bug/feature where if I single click the window's top bar when it's full screen, it gets resizes and starts a tiling behavior.
If seen others ask about this, and I know I can disable the enhanced tiling to fix this. But that also disables other useful features like corner tiling or top/bottom tiling which I want to keep.
How can I disable just the single click on the bar behaivor without disabling the tiling assitant?

Suggest reporting it as a bug. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting
